# Browse from specific folder or url only

Tags: javascript

I want to allow user to browse on a specific folder or a web url only. Here is my actual js code that only allow me to browse all folder on a pc:

```
var imghtml='<div id="qrfile"><canvas id="out-canvas" width="320" height="240"></canvas>'+
    '<div id="imghelp">Select a QR'+
    '<br>or drag & drop here'+
    '<input type="file" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)"/>'+
    '</div>'+
'</div>';
```

Is there a way that i can allow user to browse from a specific folder or a specific url folder on web?

Comment: I believe you can't do that, or if you can, it won't be with js. Javascript works on client side so it works on your browser and local machine. To make this possible you'll need to use server side languages like php or asp. Using one of those you can read the content of your webserver folder and show it to browser. If you search google for "php file browser" you'll have lots of examples on how to do it

Comment: my system is implemented with js or else i would use php, any suggestions guys

Comment: @user3399482 You need server-side language like php and help of _css_ to visualize web server files and folders in _Browse..._ dialog or _Desktop Folder_ view.

Comment: @Coder do you have any tutorial on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't use javascript to list/browse Web server folders, you need server side language.. `php`, `asp.net` etc. to do that with `javascript / jQuery AJAX` to navigate among different folders without refreshing the whole page.
2. With server-side language, you can't open `Browse...` dialog but you can apply `css` on folder contents to present a view like `Browse...` dialog and `Desktop folder view`.
3. **Without permissions, you can't access any folder outside of your web application.** If you use `shared hosting`, you can only access the web folders that are inside your web application.

In `php`, you can use [**scandir**](http://pk1.php.net/scandir) (php 5) or [**opendir(), readdir(), closedir()**](http://pk1.php.net/readdir) functions (php 4) to list files and folders.

Here is just an idea for visualizing desktop and folders:
[**ExtJs Desktop Sample App**](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/desktop/desktop.html)

Comment: But can't we merge php and js to make it work? any sample code?